# How to handle modal dialog box in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

There is a scenario where I get the modal dialog box when I tried to login.

I am not able to handle login scenario because **webdriver** is not getting access to the modal dialog box. Is there any way to handle this?

See the details in below image:
[image]

```
public class TwitterLogin 
{

    static WebDriver driver;
    static String baseUrl="myURL";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        //******Click on Login Link**********//
        WebElement LoginButton= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='Button StreamsLogin js-login']"));
        LoginButton.click();

        WebElement UsernameTextbox=    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@name,'email]')]"));
        UsernameTextbox.clear();
        UsernameTextbox.sendKeys("uName");

        WebElement PasswdTextbox=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@type,'password')]"));
        PasswdTextbox.clear();
        PasswdTextbox.sendKeys("1234");

     }

}
```

> After clicking on Login button, I'm not able to enter username & password.

Comment: What code have you written for it? Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36126795/edit) your post and add the code.

Comment: Hi Jason,
I was tried code up to the launching Url & click on Login button. But when I tried to locate elements using xpath directly, It wont happens.It means I'm unable to switch on that modal dialogbox.  Is there any way to switch on that dialogbox?

Comment: Sorry, I really can't help you unless I see the code you've written. Maybe you XPath is incorrect. Or the issue could be something else.

Comment: Explain the down votes please... Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just write the following code after click on login button:

```
Thread.sleep(3000); //i use here wait implicit wait. Try to use explicit wait here.

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.Icon.Icon--close.Icon--medium.dismiss")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks Noor. I have tried by adding big timeout & it's working now. See below is my code-

Comment: hey, dont mind boss you are correct & I accepted that.
Above code, what I hv tried it's also working.

Comment: Why the question has getting downvotes again and again. I want to ask the reason is anything missed? Please explain..

Comment: @BharatMane Actually, when any user search and get your question, he can downvote it wisely or   unconsciously. Actually i don't know who down vote this question.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In **Python** , work with **Selenium 4** and later versions:

- copy selector path
- wait to open new dialog

  time.sleep(5)

  phone_path='div:nth-child(4) > span > div:nth-child(3) > button'

  log_in_phone = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, phone_path)

  log_in_phone.click()